# Prove there doesn't exist a such continuous function $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Prove there doesn't exist a continuous function $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ is one-to-one on $\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}$ while not one-to-one on $\Bbb{Q}$.

Well, I get stuck at the beginning.  I think we must do this by constructing some contradiction. But I don't know what assumptions to make:  either that there exists such a function  or that $f$ is one-to-one on both $\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: Start by assuming $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, and consider the closed interval $[a,b]$. What theorems do you have available regarding the properties of continuous functions on a closed interval?

Comment: What do you mean by one-to-one? Is it that f is bijective?

Comment: @StatisticDean: no, one-to-one means injective.

Comment: Hint: use that if two sets $A,B$ are included in an interval $[c,d], c < d$, s.t. both their complements are countable, then their intersection is non-empty, and actually uncountable - (where you assume $f(a)=f(b)$ for rationals $a<b$, pick $x_0$ in $[a,b]$ s.t  $f(x_0) \neq f(a)$ - exists by the assumption of injectivity on irrationals and can assume wlog $f(x_0) > f(a)$- and pick $[c,d]$ the interval $[f(a), f(x_0)] = [f(b), f(x_0)]$, while for $A,B$ the image of the irrationals in $[a,x_0], [x_0,b]$ respectively which are sent by $f$ to $[c,d]$

Comment: @LOIS:  I edited to improve English, but feel free to [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3136251/edit) further if I changed your intent

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be a function such that $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a\neq b$ both in $\Bbb Q$.

Then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)$ is a local minimum or maximum for $f$.

In a small neighborhood of $c$ the function $f$ must be $2$ to $1$, i.e. for all $y$ close to $f(c)$ from above or below there are exactly two values $x_1,x_2$ close to $c$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

This sets up an involution $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$ in a small neighborhood of $c$. Since there are uncountably many $y$, and since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, there must be two such $x_1, x_2$ which are both in $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Hence $f$ cannot be injective on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

One argument using measure theory. Let's consider a function $f$, injective on $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and not injective on $\mathbb Q$. We can find two numbers $p\neq q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $f(p)= f(q)$; WLOG we can suppose that $max_{[p,q]}(f)> f(p)$, so by continuity of f, (let's call $c$ the point where the maximum is reached), there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that if $|x- c| <\alpha$, $f(x) > f(p)$. Now let's consider the set  $f_{inj} =\{x \in \mathbb R, \exists  y \neq x \in \mathbb R, f(x) = f(y)\}$; by our hypothesis $f_{inj} \subset \mathbb Q$ and has Lebesgue measure $0$, but by our continuity argument $[c-\alpha, c +\alpha] \subset f_{inj}$ and so $\mu (f_{inj}) > 2 \cdot \alpha > 0$. This is a contradiction, and $f$ has to be injective on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I feel like the answer by Andrea Mori is more suited to this question. However, this answer is more general and extends to any set of Lebesgue measure 0 (instead of countable).